# Como trocar o menor valor de um vetor com o maior valor?

Tags: java

Por enquanto só conseguir encontrar o menor e o maior, mas não consigo trocar as posições.

```
for(int i=0; i < vetor.length; i++){
    temp = vetor[i];


    if(maior < temp){
        maior  = vetor[i];
        vetor[i] = menor;
        menor = maior;
    }
     if(menor > temp){
        menor  = vetor[i];
        vetor[i] = maior;
        maior = menor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Voce quer ordenar o vetor?

Comment: Não, preciso inverter a posição do menor valor com o maior.                   ex: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} {9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1}

Comment: o vetor ja esta ordenado? Se ja, nao precisa de nada disso ai, so trocar a primeira e a ultima. Edita a pergunta e explica melhor o cenario, nao esta claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de resolver esse problema. A que eu particularmente acho mais eficiente é armazenado os índices (posição no vetor) do maior e menor elemento do vetor, pois assim minimiza a quantidade de acessos à memória, e então usando-os para trocar os valores:

```
int main(){

    int indiceMaior, indiceMenor;
    int auxiliar;

    //inicializa os índices com 0
    indiceMaior = indiceMenor = 0;

    for(int i=1; i < vetor.length; i++){

        if(vetor[i] > vetor[indiceMaior]) indiceMaior = i;

        if(vetor[i] < vetor[indiceMenor]) indiceMenor = i;
    }

    //armazenamos o maior valor para não perder-lo, 
    //pois iremos sobreescrever com o menor valor
    auxiliar = vetor[indiceMaior];
    vetor[indiceMaior] = vetor[indiceMenor];
    vetor[indiceMenor] = auxiliar;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo meu amigo!!!!!!!! Deu certo aqui

Comment: Que bom! Não tem de quê.

Caso esta resposta tenha resolvido seu problema e/ou te ajudado.

Dê um Up Vote e selecione como resposta aceita ( clique no "v" );

Answer (score 0):

Você deve salvar o maior e o menor número separadamente e apenas depois de fechada a chave do laço você troca as duas variáveis (maior e menor).
Além de que você tem de salvar também os índice, não só seu valores.

```
    maior = vetor[0];
    menor = vetor[0];

    for(int i=0; i < vetor.length; i++){
        atual = vetor[i];

        if(atual > maior){
            indiceMaior  = i;
            maior = vetor[i];
        }
         if(atual < menor){
            indiceMenor  = i;
            menor = vetor[i];
        }
    }

    vetor[indiceMenor] = maior;
    vetor[indiceMaior] = menor;
```